# Is there any Django-esque PHP framework I can use?

Tags: php, django

I really love working with Django and Python, when I go back to PHP I feel [lugered](http://img.coxnewsweb.com/B/04/01/90/image_7190014.jpg)/restricted... I tried Zend/Kohana/CodeIgniter/CakePHP but none of them are really as nice...

Does anyone know of some php framework that's heavily influenced by Django? Or at least the templating system?

Comment: Isn't that kinda like asking for a Sega Genesis-like system heavily influenced by the Playstation 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided on hosting my client's application on my server instead of doing it in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

maybe [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)?

Comment: CakePHP is looking rather dated nowdays. I would avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Akelos Framework](http://www.akelos.org/) which is described as Rails in PHP. Django is not Rails, but they are quite similar: MVC (MVT in Django), nice ORM, migrations (in case of Django You have to use an external tool) etc., so maybe Akelos would fit You.

**Edit:** I've just found [Pluf](http://www.pluf.org/).

The site says:

> Simple, elegant and easy for people used to Django but in PHP5 so easy to deploy all over the world.

I have never tried it so I cannot recommend it or not.

**Edit2:** If You are looking for template system You may try [Open Power Template](http://www.invenzzia.org/en/projects/open-power-libraries/open-power-template). Some of the features:

> Advanced support for declarative programming - tell, what you want to see, not how it is supposed to work.
>
> Blocks - easy-to-write instructions evaluated at runtime.
>
> Components - creating HTML forms with templates never was so easy.
>
> Smart HTML escaping and XSS filtering syntax techniques.

Answer (score 2):

For the templating subpart of your question, Django's templating system is actually very similar to (and possibly inspired by) the [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) template engine.

Smarty turned into a monstrosity of tens of thousands of lines of code, however, and so in response [Template Lite](http://templatelite.sourceforge.net/) was created, though I think nowadays Smarty is trying to improve their performance.

I know Kohana can use nearly any template engine (though some of the helpers may not be available); I am not familiar enough with any of the other PHP frameworks to say definitively about those.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [QCodo](http://www.qcodo.com/).  It's completely OO, with a good templating system, a solid ORM, i18n support, and a code generator which analyzes your database and generates all of your CRUD functionality.  It allows for rapid web application development on a whole different level than the other PHP frameworks.  Don't bother if you're a procedural coder or weak on your object oriented programming skills.

Comment: I'd also suggest QCubed, a community fork of QCodo, that has all of the benefits outlined above PLUS jQuery-based plugins.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option for php 5.3..

http://li3.me/

(Previously CakePHP 3)

I believe Symfony has a Django like template component.. but I cannot say for sure as I never used Django before :)

http://www.symfony-project.org/

Comment: I forgot to mention Yii it's pretty nice too :)

http://www.yiiframework.com/